# How to use the inbuilt 3G Modem with a SIM directly inserted in my laptop?

Tags: laptop, modem, 3g

I have a laptop- HP dm4 1203TU. It has a built in 3G module. The problem is I don't know how to use it. When I insert a 3G SIM inside the slot. It just tries to search the signal provider and after a couple of minutes, without a msg or report simply stops searching for network. Can anyone please let me know how to use the inbuilt modem in my laptop?.

Comment: Add more information.  Did you install the software that accompanied the SIM from your internet service provider?  Did your ISP give you specific instructions as to how to activate your service?  What steps did you follow from them, and what were the results from those steps?  In general, your ISP typically provides you with what you need, after you tell them what you have for hardware, when you purchase their service.

Comment: -1 for failing to add more information.

Comment: the 3G slots don't work with SIMs in India

Answer (score 0):

I have an Acer laptop with built-in 3G. It came with some software called Acer 3G Coonection manager. Apparently the drivers provide a COM3 which is used by Windows built-in Dialup networking. It also provides a utility 'Acer 3G Connection Manager', which has a status line which tells me network type (WCDMA/HSPA etc) and network name.

I use Telenor in Sweden, and I had to confirm multiple times that I did not want a dongle when I ordered it. Apparently that was unusual. Then I had to call support at one time, and I managed to be connected to somebody who told me to change my APN setting.

It works reasonably well. Sometimes I can connect the network menu, but sometimes I have to use the Acer Connection Manager to connect. Only occasionally do I need to restart my computer.

If your providers support tells you that they only support their own dongle, look for drivers/software on HP:s web site. You could also try the manufacturer of the 3G module.